# Is someone granted a role said to be "roled"? Or "rolled"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

This came up while trying to name things while writing an app, specifically, naming the class that represents a user and the roles they have in the system (e.g. student, administrator, etc).

AFAIK it's not commonly used, but it's concise and seems natural to me to describe a user who has been granted any role as a "*roled user*".  A coworker spelled it differently, referring everywhere to a "*rolled user*".

I'm inclined to think those mean rather different things.  I haven't been able to confirm that by searching because I can't avoid getting overwhelmed with irrelevant results for "roll" rather than "role" or "rolex" rather than "roled".

**Is "*roled*" a word?  Does it mean what I think it means?  Does "*rolled*" also mean what I think "*roled*" should mean?**

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roled vs. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rolled

Comment: Be wary of the fact that Wiktionary gives "roled" word status.  It's missing from other online dictionaries, such as Merriam-Webster.  At best, I'd say it was an extrapolated word, which is to say that if you used it, someone would understand that you combined the word "role" with the "-ed" ending to form an adjective.  Actors who are given roles are said to be "casted" as such and such a character, not "roled".  In your situation, I might use "designated" or "assigned" (an administrator).

Comment: @Steven If someone were described as being _casted_, I would expect them to be in India and have been assigned to a caste. In my experience, at least, actors are _cast_ when given parts, not casted.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I hadn't considered using "*rolt user*"

Comment: Try this: *assigned*.

Comment: When it comes to naming classes, ask yourself if there are any users without a role? Isn't being a user a role? That would make the concept of a 'roled user' irrelevant.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You're right; it was a typo.  Cast, not casted.

Comment: @DJClayworth, in this code "User" is the generic user class that comes with the authentication library, so we have a different class for user information that the app gets post-login from another source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your concern is whether the word is given credence in highly regarded dictionaries, *Oxford English Dictionary* can resolve the issue.

The *OED* does, in fact, define "role" as a transitive verb in the fashion you are describing.

> **role** *v. trans.* -- To provide with a role indicator.

Cited use:

> The presence of the connective merely ensures that the first word in the multi-word phrase is roled and stored.

- *Program* · 1976.

**Roled** is marked as a derivative word, so you would be safe in the realm of English using the word in this fashion.

It's worth noting that the word is provided with a context: *Computing. rare.* So if you are more concerned with being understood by a layperson than you are with using sanctioned English words, you might avoid using "role" in this way.

The *OED* offers no definition under "rolled" for this meaning, and none that is cross-referenced to the verb "role" or "roled."

Answer (score 2):

'roled' is a bit borderline on being a real word. Only self-editable dictionaries seem to have it. More strict dictionaries do not. I would recommend against it in formal writing.

**In any case, rolled does not mean the same as roled.**

'Roll' is not a synonym of 'role'. It [has many meanings](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/roll), but all of them are related to moving circularly or on wheels. Using 'rolled' where 'roled' is meant will cause confusion. A rolled user would be one wrapped up in a tortilla.

Confusion is sometimes caused by the existence of the word 'enrolled', which means to have made something a member of something. It doesn't imply having a role.

Answer (score 0):

'Rolled' is the past participle of 'to roll'.

'Role' is a noun. The only possible derivation of 'roled' is as the noun 'role' verbified, and then take its past participle. This is a very long stretch to interpret 'roled', given that it is not a recognized word.

Comment: By the way, Wiktionary is crap.